# Rails 3, nested resource, No route matches [PUT]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes

I'm literately going crazy with this one. I have been searching the answer and trying everything I find, including related questions & answers here on stackoverflow and still can't make it work.

I'm working with a nested resource and I can't make the form work. I always get errors, such as No route matches [PUT] "/galleries/1/photos"

The form is here: /galleries/1/photos/1/edit

routes.rb

```
resources :galleries do
  resources :photos
end
resources :galleries
resources :photos
```

photos_controller.rb

```
def new
  @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
  @photo = @gallery.photos.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
 end

def edit
  @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
  @photo = @gallery.photos.build(params[:photo])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @photo.save
      format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end

def update
  @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:gallery_id])
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @photo.update_attributes(params[:photo])
      format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@gallery, @photo], :url => gallery_photos_path(params[:gallery_id]), :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :title %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I have also tried `form_for([@gallery, @photo], :html => {:multipart => true})` and `form_for(@photo, :url => gallery_photos_path(@gallery), :html => {:multipart => true})`

**UPDATE**

Here is a portion of rake routes.

```
gallery_photos GET    /galleries/:gallery_id/photos(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"photos"}
    POST   /galleries/:gallery_id/photos(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"photos"}
new_gallery_photo GET    /galleries/:gallery_id/photos/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"photos"}
edit_gallery_photo GET    /galleries/:gallery_id/photos/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"photos"}
gallery_photo GET    /galleries/:gallery_id/photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"photos"}
    PUT    /galleries/:gallery_id/photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"photos"}
    DELETE /galleries/:gallery_id/photos/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photos"}
```

Comment: This is very weird. I changed to form to `form_for(@photo)` and went to this URL: photos/1/edit and when I submit the form I get Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"photos"}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to specify the URL, which was wrong for the update anyway.  Try

```
<%= form_for([@gallery, @photo], :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Answer off top of my head. I don't have working example, but hope it helps.

In deed, according to your `rake routes`, you don't have a route:

```
[PUT] "/galleries/1/photos"
```

If I'm not mistaken, your form points to invalid action: `gallery_photos_path` will return an index of photos in gallery with id `:gallery_id`. I think, :url parameter of the form should be something like:

```
:url => gallery_photo_path(params[:gallery_id], params[:id])
```

OR you can specify it without using Rails helpers:

```
:url => "/galleries/#{params[:gallery_id]}/photos/#{params[:id]}"
```

Also, if you are trying to create nested resource, I don't think you need these lines in your routes file:

```
resources :galleries
resources :photos
```

Comment: If I remove those lines and I go to /galleries/1/photos/1/edit I get this error: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"photos", :format=>nil, :id=>#<Photo id: 1, title...`